# Fetching an image from google app engine ndb

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Can someone verify/correct my method of accessing an image that is part of a ndb.Model class?

This is my MainPage handler:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def get(self):
    guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                      DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
    greetings_query = Greeting.query(
        ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
    greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

    template_values = {
        'greetings': greetings,
        'guestbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(guestbook_name),
    }

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

This is my index.html template code:

```
{% for greeting in greetings %}
  <div><img src="/img?key_id={{ greeting.key.id() }}" />
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my image handler:

```
class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    greeting = ndb.get(self.request.get('key_id'))
    if greeting.avatar:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        self.response.out.write(greeting.avatar)
        self.response.write('it works')
    else:
        self.error(404)
        self.response.out.write('No image')
```

The idea is that I store my image in a blob in my Greeting NDB Model. I then try to get that image by populating the main page with my MainPage handler which calls my Image handler. I pass the specific ndb entry key via my template and then retrieve the key from the template in the Image handler. I then attempt to display the blob attribute by getting the ndb entry using the key.
Here's the error trace:

[image]

Comment: use https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#get-data : self.request.GET('key_id'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of loading data doesn't/can't work, you wrote:

```
greeting = ndb.get(self.request.get('key_id'))
```

As the exception indicates, the module (`ndb`) has no `get` method, and even if there was one, how could it know the model to look for? The right way to do it would be:

```
greeting_id = int(self.request.get('key_id'))
greeting = Greeting.get_by_id(greeting_id)
```

Notice that we're converting `key_id` to an integer, you're not going into detail about how the id is assigned but most likely it's auto generated, and so an integer; if you were to use the request data as-is, the database would be unable to find it (request data is always a string, quite literally).

Also, the right method for writing the response is this:

```
self.response.write(greeting.avatar)
```

As you can read [here in the docs](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/response.html). Using `out` is "outdated" (from the old framework), only supported for compatibility purposes, and ultimately the same thing, so by writing to it twice you're effectively corrupting your image data.

If you want debugging information you should use a more appropriate method:

```
import logging
logging.info('it works')
```

The solution to the comments below:

```
guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name', DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
greeting_id = int(self.request.get('key_id'))
greeting = Greeting.get_by_id(greeting_id, parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm getting a different error now saying that 'greeting' is a NoneType object. Am I storing it incorrectly or something? I feel like I'm really close... From the local datastore, I see that my uploaded image is stored as binary, which I'm assuming means the uploading worked. All that is left is to retrieve that. Why am I retrieving an object that is None?

Comment: I see that you're using an ancestor to query for your greetings, so you may need to use that when fetching them, like: `Greeting.get_by_id(greeting_id, parent=guestbook_key)`